# How to solve for x in the equation x^20 = 16.367

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation

$$x^{20} = 16.367$$

How do I solve for $x$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Wouldn't the answer be $x = \pm\sqrt[20]{16.367}$, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Hey John. That was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for all solutions, or just one?

Comment: A practical way of doing the calculation before computers was to use logarithms

Comment: One solution was all that was needed. Thank you for your input folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this from the unanswered stack, since the question was answered in the comments, 
$$
x^{20}= 16.367 \Longrightarrow x= \pm \sqrt[20]{16.367}= \pm (16.367)^{1/20
} \approx \pm 1.150001625\cdots
$$
where you can find more digits [at this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16.367%5E%281%2F20%29).